# Carbon: comparing date instances is giving unexpected result

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

This problem is driving me crazy.

Here is my Carbon instance:

```
$carbonTemp = CarbonImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

What I want to do is just to understand if the date here is the last day of the week.

```
$carbonTemp->equalTo($carbonTemp->endOfWeek())
```

If `$date = '2021-08-08'` which is the last day of this week, the result above must be true, right?

It is giving me FALSE !!

Even though `$carbonTemp->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d')` is giving me '2021-08-08'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**endOfWeek()** returns last day of week and time 23:59:59.999999. Therefore it is necessary to use **endOfDay()** method when creating date.

```
$carbonTemp = CarbonImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->endOfDay();
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding the question well and giving accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you created CarbonImmutable object, so endOfWeek will not work.

Create a normal Carbon date:

```
$carbonTemp = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Comment: Sorry but this is a bad answer :) If I do it that way - which I did - the instances will be always same because of $carbonTemp->endOfWeek() will change the mutable object.

Comment: You can not edit an Immutable date, so it's the only way. If don't, one possibility is create or clone the date, and make two different objects. $carbon->copy()

Comment: Yes you can not edit an immutable date, that's why I'm using it. If I do it like you say, the result is going to be ALWAYS TRUE. Please think about it.

Comment: And, endOfWeek, actually other functions too, work on both mutable and immutable Carbon instances.

Comment: @AdemTepe you need two different Carbon date objects, the answer is not bad, but incomplete. Please be friendly when someone tries to help.

Comment: @MarcGarcia Maybe its a good idea to add the solution with Carbon copy to your answer.

Comment: @GertB. I was really trying to be friendly and explicative. I just think that the answer is sloppy. I would like to learn the solution with Carbon copy if it is valid, it's good to know different solutions to one problem.

Comment: @GertB. The answer you marked right it's the same answer as mine, so, my answer was correct

Comment: @MarcGarcia i didn't mark anything as accepted, since i didn't ask the question.  (And i agree)